# What is the difference between these two pieces of code concerning lists nested inside dictionaries?

Tags: python

I am learning python by reading the 'Python Crash Course' book so I'm still a beginner, what I want to know is the difference between these two pieces of code as they both seem to be the same to me but give different results.

```
names={
    'first' : ['john','mike'],
}
for name in names.keys():
    print(name[1])
```

This gives the result 'i'.

```
names={
    'first' : ['john','mike'],
}
for name in names.keys():
    print(names[name][1])
```

This gives my expected result; 'mike'.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They are not the same, `names[name][1]` is not the same as `name[1]`

Comment: to really understand what's happening, you should put another print before doing all that. print the "name" variable, and then try to reason it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`names.keys()` will return all keys of the `names` dictionary. Hence the only key is just: `first`.

`for name in names.keys()` will go through the keys one by one, in this case it will only observe the single key above.

Thus ... `name` here stores the value `"first"`

`"first"[1]` will return `'i'` and `names['first']` will return `['john','mike']`, hence `names['first'][1]` will return `"mike"` (the second element of that list)

Comment: Thank you very much!
I always thought the ```
names={
    'first' : ['john','mike'],
}```
makes a list called first in this manner ```
first=['john','mike']``` Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand this example:

```
>>> names = {'first': ['john', 'mike']}
>>> for key in names.keys():
...     print(f'Current key is "{key}"')
...     print(f'Second element of "{key}" is "{key[1]}"')
...     print(f'Value of key "{key}" is "{names[key]}"')
...     print(f'Second element of "{names[key]}" is "{names[key][1]}"')
...     
Current key is "first"
Second element of "first" is "i"
Value of key "first" is "['john', 'mike']"
Second element of "['john', 'mike']" is "mike"
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, `name` refers to the (only) key in `names`, the string `'first'`.

In the first loop, you print `'first'[1]`, which is `'i'`.

In the second loop, you use the name to get a value from `names`; `names[name] == ['john', 'mike']`, so `names[name][1]` is `['john', 'mike'][1] == 'mike'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
names={
    'first' : ['john','mike'],
}
for name in names.keys():
    print(name[1])
```

First `names` is a dictionary which uses keys, not indexes. The 'key' for the dictionary in this example is `first`. Lets look at the dictionary:

```
>>> names
{'first': ['john', 'mike']}
```

We can see that there is one key `first` and that key has a `list` as the value. The list has two items `john` and `mike`.

When you do the for loop, you are iterating over each item in the dictionary. Specifically in your case, you are iterating over the keys. In this example there is only one key: `first`.

One thing that might be confusing you is you are using the variable `name`. Let's change it to `i` for the sake of example:

```
for i in names.keys():
    print(i)
```

This will return `first` because that is the only key in the dictionary. You can replace `i` with (almost) any variable name you want.

So we have a str with the value of `first` and we want the 2nd character from that string. Remember, python starts at 0, so `[1]` is the 2nd character of the string `first` which is `i`.

Now, in the second code block, you have `names[name][1]]`. Remember that the `names` dictionary has the value `{'first': ['john', 'mike']}`. Again, let's change the word `name` to `i` to help see what's happening:

```
for i in names.keys():
    print(names[i][1])
```

Again, the only key we have is `first`, so when the for loop iterates, it will go i == `first`, then end. Lets try this:

```
>>> names['first']
['john', 'mike']
```

This returns a list of the two names. If we take the first value of the list with `>>> names['first'][1]` we get `mike`.

So, in summary, in the first example you are taking a slice of the key which is a str, and in the second example you are returning the first element of the value of the dictionary of the given key.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `names.keys()`, the function returns a list with all the keys in your dictionary. When you run a loop, `name` will be the elements of your list, the string `"first"` in that case. So, when you call `name[1]`, it's the same as calling `"first"[1]`, which will return the second character of the string: "i".

In the second code, when you call `names[name]`, it's the same as calling `names["first"]`, which returns a list(`['john','mike']`) and then you can print the second element of your list (`"mike"`)